# MVC 5.2.3 - Globalization - DateTime & Decimal with Range

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, globalization

Long story short, I started a new project using MVC 5.2.3 (with all updated JS frameworks) expecting that many of the issues I had with validations from MVC 2 were solved, ***how wrong was I***.

Basically I am driving myself crazy trying to provide validation to `DateTime` and `Decimal`.
With the decimal field, using browsers in EN and DE (cultures) I am getting problems with comma and point (decimal division) and with the range that I am setting.

With the `DateTime` I even tried a `DisplayFormat` just to display the Date and not the time, and anyway the order of day/month/year with separations with `.` or `/` or `-` are simply failing.

**Examples:**

- In DE - Type: 999,999 --> Result: ERROR "Das Feld "D1 DE" muss zwischen 0 und 999,9999 liegen. " - **should be accepted**.
- In EN - Type: 999.999 --> Result: is accepted as it should be (correct)

The same applies to the datetime display format and similar JS validations....

I share with you guys what I have at the moment:

TestObject

```
public class TestObject
{       
    ....
    [Display(Name = "D2", ResourceType = typeof(WebApplication1.Models.Res.TestObject))]
    [Range(0, 999.9999)]
    public decimal? D1 { get; set; }
    // On DBContext I have defined the range/precision
    // modelBuilder.Entity<TestObject>().Property(x => x.D2).HasPrecision(7, 4);

    [Display(Name = "Date1", ResourceType = typeof(WebApplication1.Models.Res.TestObject))]
    //[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:dd\/MM\/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

view.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.D2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.D2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.D2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

_layout.cshtml

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/globalize/globalize.js" type="text/javascript"></script></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/globalize/cultures/globalize.culture.de.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/globalize/cultures/globalize.culture.en-US.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

    <script>
  $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) ||
        !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
  }

  $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) ||
        Globalize.parseDate(value);
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    Globalize.culture('@System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture');
  });
</script>
```

DecimalModelBinder

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                                 ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    object result = null;

    // Don't do this here!
    // It might do bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError
    // and there is no RemoveModelError!
    // 
    // result = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

    string modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
    string attemptedValue =
        bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName).AttemptedValue;

    // Depending on CultureInfo, the NumberDecimalSeparator can be "," or "."
    // Both "." and "," should be accepted, but aren't.
    string wantedSeperator = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator;
    string alternateSeperator = (wantedSeperator == "," ? "." : ",");

    if (attemptedValue.IndexOf(wantedSeperator) == -1
        && attemptedValue.IndexOf(alternateSeperator) != -1)
    {
        attemptedValue =
            attemptedValue.Replace(alternateSeperator, wantedSeperator);
    }

    try
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelMetadata.IsNullableValueType
            && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attemptedValue))
        {
            return null;
        }

        result = decimal.Parse(attemptedValue, NumberStyles.Any);
    }
    catch (FormatException e)
    {
        bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(modelName, e);
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

Global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal?), new DecimalModelBinder());
       ...
    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;

        string culture = null;
        if (context.Request.UserLanguages != null && Request.UserLanguages.Length > 0)
        {
            culture = Request.UserLanguages[0];
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        }
    }
}
```

web.config

```
    <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
```

Comment: So, what's the problem exactly?

Comment: As I said, the validations are NOT working correctly neither in EN or DE and probably in any other culture.....

Comment: "Not working correctly" is not a proper problem statement. What do you do, what do you expect to happen, what actually happens and what have you tried to resolve those differences?

Comment: What does the `Globalize.culture('@System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture')` look like in your HTML?

Comment: @CodeCaster Globalize.culture('de');

Comment: Could please someone reopen this question? Thanks

Comment: Create a smaller sample that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I also needed to create my own range method.....
Now it seems to be working.

```
$.validator.methods.range = function(value, element, param) {
    console.log('----------------');
    console.log(value);
    console.log(element);                
    var globalizedValue = value.replace(",", ".");
    console.log(param[0]);
    var globalizedValueParam0 = param[0];
    console.log(param[1]);
    var globalizedValueParam1 = param[1];        
    console.log(globalizedValueParam0);
    console.log(globalizedValueParam1);

    //return this.optional(element) || (globalizedValue >= param[0] && globalizedValue <= param[1]);
    return this.optional(element) || (globalizedValue >= globalizedValueParam0 && globalizedValue <= globalizedValueParam1);
};
```

Comment: This is a bad approach as you are hard-coding the symbols.

Comment: I'm welcome for better solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

According the error message I see that you are showing data correctly, but don't parse it right way.

I think that the problem is here:

```
$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) ||
        !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
}
```

<strike>Can't see where is a culture usage here, may be some of the classes aren't got the right culture. According to standards. `999,999` in German stands for `999 999` - big integer without any numbers in precision part. Check the input for your javascript and try to debug it.</strike>

First of all, `enableClientBasedCulture` isn't in use at the current time ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx)). It looks like your Globalization class is being set to the `ENG` culture always, even if you do the explicit all at `document.ready` event. Try to set explicitly the German culture in `web.config`, and check your logic. It should works for `DE` but not for the `EN`. If it does, then your should provide the right culture each time you are trying to parse data.

However, if it doesn't, than the problem is not in the globalization.

Comment: I am sorry but in many European countries like Germany and Austria 999,999 means 999.999 in EN.... decimal separation is comma, if it is a point is just a VISUAL (not logical) meaning to display thousands, example: 9.999,999 in DE means 9999 real part and  0.999

Comment: May be I'm not right with separator role, but I still can't see any ways you provide current culture in javascript validators. They treat german decimals as english thousands, and that's why your code is broken. May be you should set the culture for each method?

Comment: if I have that JS code, using DE I only get error regarding the range... if I remove the JS I get a error saying that is not a valid number.... so I believe that the culture is correct, but not the validation that checks the 0,999 part.....

Comment: I don't suggest to remove the `JS`. Try to set culture explicitly before each `parse`: Globalize.culture('@System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture');